# static list keeps its content between different executions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web, model-view-controller, static

i have a web page with server side written in C#.
i have a class:

```
public class A{

    private static List<A> all = new List<A>();
    static A()
    {
        A notExists = new A(0, "", 0, "gray", 0);
        all.Add(notExists);
    }
    .......

    public A(........){
    //some code here
    A.all.Add(this);
    }
}
```

in the controleer of the page I use this constructor a few times.
in the first time I run the code, everything works fine. i stop the execution for working and adding coding more, but in the second time (and further) I execute the code, even before the first time i call the constructor the list 'all' already contains all the elements from the previous execution.

Why does it happen? I know static will make the code run only once, but still i closed it. there should be no trace for the past. so why?

Comment: *"static will make the code run only once"* - this is too narrow a view of what `static` does. Applied to *fields* (like `all`), it means that there's only one memory location for the variable rather than one for each instance of the declaring type (here, `A`). The *type initializer* (or "static constructor" as it's often called) will only run once but merely as a consequence of the fact that it initializes static members and only *needs* to be called once.

Comment: As for *"still i closed it"*, I suspect you think you've terminated the process when in fact you haven't. Web applications are services just waiting for requests and are designed to stay running when there's no page request being processed. It's impossible to say, though, because it's unclear what you *really* did.

Comment: i'm using visual studio. to run I use the "run" button (IIS Express - Google Chrome). and to terminate I just click the "stop debugging" button

Comment: "Stop debugging" doesn't always close IIS Express.

Comment: @madreflection so how can i close it? when I press the button it closes the Chrome tab. what else can i do?

Comment: There's an icon in the system tray. Right-click, Exit (and confirm).

Comment: works! this is the answer! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
the problem was that the IIS Express wasn't really closed when i stopped debugging.
I needed to click the icon in the system tray. Right-click, Exit (and confirm)